# App crashing when installed from Play store

Tags: android-intent

My Android app crashes when it is installed from Play store while launching but when I launch the same app when I install the apk directly from the device, it is not crashing. Any idea what could be causing this? The crash log I received from the play store is below.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.codingsquare.pgs/com.codingsquare.pgs.PGSActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.codingsquare.pgs.PGSActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.codingsquare.pgs-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-
lib/com.codingsquare.pgs-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

When the same code is run through Eclipse debugger, the app is working fine. Even on play store when we installed through the beta channel, it worked, but when it is updated to production it stopped working. Any idea on the discrepancy with the app behavior.

Comment: record your `logcat` without it it's very difficult to give any reason

Comment: Could it be because you are using proguard in the final release ?

Comment: If you are using eclipse, then make sure when u run application(in release mode to generate signed apk) , check that from menu>Project>Build Automatically is unchecked.

Comment: download release version from play and look at logcat.Or use Android studio to build release version of .apk and then adb install from command line.

Comment: @MD, Updated my original query with crash log.

Comment: did you found out any solution?

Comment: Had the same problem, but a little bit more weird.
Tested my release apk generated locally - worked fine. 
Uploaded on Google play and after installing the app from there - crashing on start.
Uninstalled, installed again from Google Play - works fine.
Did anyone have this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you create a "release" APK for the play store, gradle runs proguard, which can make some of your classes invisible to your code if not configured properly.

As a quick test to make sure this is the problem, you can add the following code in your `android{}` section of your `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    debug {
    }
}
```

Comment: I can try that,but I have to upload a new build to Play store, which i will be doing shortly. But I uploaded this build to Play store released as a Beta, it worked and then i promoted it to production and then it started having this issue. So if it is a build issue as you suspected, wouldn't the same issue happen when i released is for beta also. I promoted the same APK to production and so even the Beta build must also have same issue if it is related proguard!

Comment: Well, this actually worked. I updated the build.gradle as you suggested and it started working.

Comment: This helped me solve a completely unrelated problem, so thank you from 4 years in the future!