# Android app only crashes when installed from App store in production: Resource not found in classpath: kotlin/kotlin.kotlin_builtins

Tags: android, kotlin

I made an Android app that works fine when run locally and worked when installed from an internal test track but once I released it to production the public version installed from the Google Play Store crashes instantly when opened.

Stack trace from logcat:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2019-04-07 08:52:53.918 806-806/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.alexmojaki.quiggles, PID: 806
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alexmojaki.quiggles/com.alexmojaki.quiggles.MainMenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource not found in classpath: kotlin/kotlin.kotlin_builtins
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource not found in classpath: kotlin/kotlin.kotlin_builtins
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl.createBuiltInPackageFragmentProvider(BuiltInsLoaderImpl.kt:55)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl.createPackageFragmentProvider(BuiltInsLoaderImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.createBuiltInsModule(KotlinBuiltIns.java:127)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltIns.<init>(JvmBuiltIns.kt:43)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltIns.<init>(JvmBuiltIns.kt:18)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.components.RuntimeModuleData$Companion.create(RuntimeModuleData.kt:58)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ModuleByClassLoaderKt.getOrCreateModule(moduleByClassLoader.kt:58)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData$2.invoke(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:37)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data$moduleData$2.invoke(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:34)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:92)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:31)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data.getModuleData(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:47)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$descriptor$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:44)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:92)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:31)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getDescriptor(KClassImpl.kt:179)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getConstructorDescriptors(KClassImpl.kt:196)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:91)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$constructors$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:44)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:92)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:31)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getConstructors(KClassImpl.kt)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getConstructors(KClassImpl.kt:235)
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:149)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.findKotlinParameterName(KotlinModule.kt:180)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.findImplicitPropertyName(KotlinModule.kt:106)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findImplicitPropertyName(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:490)
2019-04-07 08:52:53.919 806-806/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addCreatorParam(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:485)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addCreators(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:465)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:313)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:287)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:170)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription._properties(BasicBeanDescription.java:164)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findProperties(BasicBeanDescription.java:239)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._findCreatorsFromProperties(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:349)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:333)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:257)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:214)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:137)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:411)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:444)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:194)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:113)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:254)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3077)
        at com.alexmojaki.quiggles.MainMenuActivity.onCreate(MainMenuActivity.kt:140)
        at com.alexmojaki.quiggles.CommonActivity.onCreate(CommonActivity.kt:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
            ... 9 more
```

Source code: https://github.com/alexmojaki/quiggles

Play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alexmojaki.quiggles

I use Android Studio to generate a signed Android App Bundle which I upload to the Play Console.

Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 29, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6
```

Root `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/waynejo/maven" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alexmojaki.quiggles"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "public_2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13'
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8"
    implementation 'com.waynejo:androidndkgif:0.3.3'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.16'
    implementation 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: I assume `run locally` means debug build. Try release build locally and the (guessing) inspect your proguard settings

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I just built a release APK and installed it and it worked. As I said everything worked when installed from the internal track, only releasing to production changed things. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34162313/2482744) which suggested proguard might be an issue and [followed the suggestion](https://github.com/alexmojaki/quiggles/commit/abd8572feb2e152074206c594adad993bf989b63), removing mention of proguard from `app/build.gradle`. Nothing changed. `proguard-rules.pro` has always been completely commented out. No other files mention proguard.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed. Upgrading from  `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1` to `3.3.2` seems to have done it.

Alternatively it's *possible* that disabling proguard fixed the issue but that I didn't correctly install that version with that fix (although I think I did) or that something else changed (maybe on Google Play). I have no visibility into what's going on or easy tests to perform.